# why org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect cannot be cast to org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

In hibernate.xml, I have :

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
```

and here is what I'm trying to do:

```
final Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = sess.beginTransaction();
    Collection<Rfc> rfcs;
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Rfc.class);
    criteria = criteria.add(Restrictions.like(Rfc.RFC_IDENTIFIER, input.replace('*', '%')));
    rfcs = criteria.list();
    // ...
    tx.commit();
} catch (final Exception e) {
    if (tx != null) {
        tx.rollback();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
} finally {
    sess.close();
}
```

This all seems very straightforward, but I'm getting:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect cannot be cast to org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
>           at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.

Here is the relevant bit of my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <!--            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>-->
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've traced the issue to a method of org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(), where we find:

```
private Dialect constructDialect(String dialectName) {
    try {
        return ( Dialect ) classLoaderService.classForName( dialectName ).newInstance();
    }
    catch ( ClassLoadingException e ) {
        throw new HibernateException( "Dialect class not found: " + dialectName, e );
    }
    catch ( HibernateException e ) {
        throw e;
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        throw new HibernateException( "Could not instantiate dialect class", e );
    }
}
```

Attempting to instantiate a Dialog here results in the above ClassCastException.

Just to be extra sure I have the right class, I displayed all the superclasses in its hierarchy... and here is exactly what I see in my console:

class org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

class org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect

class org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect

**class org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect**

yet... sure enough, 
    org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.class.isAssignableFrom(classLoaderService.classForName( dialectName ) )
returns false.

Could this be some sort of incompatibility between versions of hibernate and the drivers provided by Postgresql?

Been tearing my hair out.  Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep.  The problem, it seems, was that I was trying to mix incompatible versions of various hibernate dependencies.  I just replaced section of the pom.xml cited above with :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I'm on to my next issue!

Answer (score 1):

That was a Hibernate known bug that has been fixed in **4.1.4.Final**

Hibernate bug report: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7084